# Pandas time operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame with information from a broker, the data show the distance traveled, time spent and the date of the race.

```
DISTANCE    TIME    DATE
9.8     51:50.92    09/08/18
11.1    55:59.70    24/08/18
11.1    49:25.20    29/08/18
```

I would like to perform an **arithmetic** operation between the records in the **"TIME"** column as differences between the times, calculate the average speed of each race.

### The problem is the following:

When transforming the text string to pandas **datetime** it remains with the following format:

```
1900-01-01 00:51:50
1900-01-01 00:55:59
1900-01-01 00:49:25
```

What I need is the time so I do the following

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format = '%M:%S')
```

Which leads me to the next problem, the column is now of type "object" and I can't perform operations of any kind on it.

How can I transform a column to **time** without losing the datetime format? and perform operations with it.

I would like, for example, to calculate speed, differences between times and frequencies between races.

Comment: What is the code you use for the operation :D

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong `df.TIME.diff()` and `df.DISTANCE / df.TIME` I've seen tutorials where they use functions like `df.TIME[0] - df.TIME[1]` I have seen tutorials in which they use functions as is and it returns the difference in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that Distance is km, use this to get your speed in km/h:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'DISTANCE':[9.5,11.1,11.1],'TIME':['51:50.92','55:59.70','49:25.20'],'DATE':['09/08/18','24/08/18','29/08/18']})


df['TIME'] = '00:' + df['TIME']
df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])
df['SPEED (km/h)']=[df['DISTANCE'][i]/(df['TIME'][i].total_seconds()/3600) for i in df.index]#total_seconds() won't work with a pandas column so you need to apply it to each TIME cell
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `to_datetime`, you could use [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html). See below:

```
df['TIME'] = '00:' + df['TIME']
df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])
```

The result of this is:

```
   DISTANCE            TIME      DATE
0       9.8 00:51:50.920000  09/08/18
1      11.1 00:55:59.700000  24/08/18
2      11.1 00:49:25.200000  29/08/18
```

You can now use mathematical operations on `TIME`. However, as mentioned in Phung Duy Phong's comment above, it's hard to say whether this will solve your issues without seeing the code you'd like to run.

Comment: `TIME` is actually of type `timedelta64[ns]`. I imagine that the ability to perform calculations on the times is more important than literally being `datetime`, but if that's wrong, OP will need to try a different approach.

Comment: If I wanted to calculate the speed of each runner in Km/m, is there any way to apply the arithmetic function / in two different types of data **float** and **datetime**?. that would be the main function of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot @cpander